# Передать параметр в компонент (vue.js)

Tags: vue.js, события, компоненты

В *vue.js 2.5* проекте делаю небольшой редактор в виде компонента с передачей в этот редактор текста.
Так как невозможно редактировать переменную `content`, переданную из родителя, то добавил переменную `editor_content`, в которую записал содержимое `content` :

```
export default {
    props: {
        content: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            default: ''
        },
    }, // props: {

mounted() {
    alert( "mounted this.content::"+(this.content) )
    this.editor_content = this.content
}, // mounted() {
```

Но, видимо, нужно другое событие, а не `mounted`, так как `this.content` выводится пустым. **Какое ?**

2) А чтобы записать измененный текст, мне нужно в моем редакторе генерировать событие средством `.$emit` и в родителе слушать это событие?

Answer (score 1):

Почти правильно.
Только prop надо заворачивать в computed.
Ну и в родителе подписываться на событие, которое эмитится наверх при изменении данных.

```js
export default {
  props: {
    content: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
  },
  computed: {
    editor_content: {
      get () {
        return this.content
      },
      set (content) {
        this.$emit('input', content)
      }
    }
  }
}
```