# Передать переменную из дочернего компонента VueJs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.7

есть основной компонент Surfing, в этот компонент импортирую другой компонент settings, и в дочернем компоненте есть переменная time, как мне передать переменную из дочернего компонента в основной?

в родительском компоненте вызываю дочку

```
<settings :nolimit="nolimit" ></settings>
```

это родитель

```
<script>
    import axios from 'axios'
    import Settings from "./Settings";
    export default {
        components: {Settings},
        name: "Surfing",
        el: '#surfing_form',
        data: function(){
            return {
                max: 60,
                maxUrl: 160,
                showInnerSettings: false,
                nolimit: false,
                eml: 0,
                form: {
                    url: '',
                    title: '',
                    politic: false,
                    type_advertising: 0,
                    time_view: 0,
                    cost: 0
                }
            }
        },
        computed: {
            costOrder: function() {
                var result = 0,
                    nolimit = this.form.type_advertising,
                    counttime = this.form.time_view;
                    priceLimit = 0;
                    priceTime = 0.090;
                    priceVip = 0.01;
                result = priceTime + priceLimit + priceVip;
                return result
            }
        },
        mounted() {

        },
        methods: {

        }
    }
</script>
```

а это Settings из него мне нужно в родителя передать vip

```
<div class="item">
                    <label for="">Разместить в VIP блоке</label>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="no-select-item" v-if="nolimit">
                        <b>Да</b>
                    </div>
                    <div class="select-item" v-else>
                        <select v-model="vip" name="vip">
                            <option v-bind:value="0">Нет</option>
                            <option v-bind:value="1">Да&nbsp;&nbsp;(+ 0.01 руб. за 1 просмотр)</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="help-info">
                        <span>?</span>
                        <div class="help-body-info"><b>VIP блок</b> - ваша ссылка будет размещена выше стандартных ссылок и выделена специальным значком VIP.</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios'
    export default {
        name: "Settings",
        props: [
            'nolimit'
        ],
        data: function(){
            return {
                countries: [],
                vip: 0,
                register: 0
            }
        },
        computed: {

        },
        mounted() {
            this.getGeo();
        },
        methods: {
            getGeo(){
                axios.get('/cabinet/countries/getlist').then((response) => {
                    this.countries = response.data
                });
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Почитайте о модуле VueX

Comment: я читал, но не  понял как использовать в дочернем компоненте и делать возврат

Comment: обычно общение "детей" с "родителями" осуществляется через события. Но можно и Vuex

Comment: а как мне передать например в дочку модель и по идее все события с моделью ведь должны передаваться в родитель?

Comment: Причем тут вообще Laravel?

Comment: [ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/985344/256824 ] [ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/768484/256824 ]